# Calling a VB6 method from a .NET DLL

Tags: dll, vb6, interop

I have a DLL written in VB 6 and another DLL written in Visual Studio 2005 (VB.NET).

Now I want to invoke the method of the VB DLL from my .NET DLL. What should I do for this?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As VB6 creates COM DLLs, Visual Studio should have no problems generating an interop stub for you. Simply add a reference to the VB6 DLL from your .NET project by selecting Add Reference in Visual Studio and finding your DLL under the COM tab. Make sure the VB6 DLL [is registered on your machine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx) before you do this.