# How to call VB6 EXE function from C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

How can I call a dot net exe from VB6 and pass some information to it? If possible, can I do the same thing, calling VB6 exe from  dot net application?

Comment: Do you mean, on the command line to the EXE?

Comment: Which way round? Your title asks about VB6 called from C#, and the questions C# called from VB6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely have to use VB6, your best bet is to call a VB6 function from C# is to export your VB6 functionality with COM, then use Interop in C# to access it:

[Calling a VB6 method from a .NET DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617846/calling-a-vb6-method-from-a-net-dll)

If you just want to invoke an .exe, you can easily do that with [ShellExec](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918) (from VB) or [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) (from C#).

Answer (score 2):

Use the Process class.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "MyApplication.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "The arguments";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Note: This is the answer to the title of your question (calling vb from c#). The fact that you then ask the total opposite question in the question text makes for a rather confusing question.