# Can Vb6 modules be used/referenced in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, module, vb6

I imported a .dll file that contains modules created from VB6. I am using VB 2017 and I was wondering if those can still be used in .NET. Is there any way or should I re-code all the modules?

Comment: "COM interop" still exists, yes; I'm not saying that is *necessarily* the best option, though...

Comment: Why rewrite it? Remember YAGNI rule.  Marc's suggestion for COM interop sounds good to me.

Comment: Surely this must be a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a VB6 method from a .NET DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617846/calling-a-vb6-method-from-a-net-dll)

Comment: @DaveInCaz Thanks! I didn’t see this before.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 "[ActiveX DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229332%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)" projects are just COM Objects that can be called from any platform that can call COM objects. Using [.NET COM Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/) one should be able to call them like any other COM object.